# network diagram using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a database table containing network information (servers, clusters etc). Is there any javascript library to show this information(after converting it to json or xml) in a network bus topology model?

```
     Server1         Server2         Cluster
      |               |               |   
      |               |               |
   ========================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could look at protovis?

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/

You have to do a little fiddling to make it work with jQuery. Any place in protovis where they use function you have to add the curly braces which have been omitted.

```
     var color = pv.Colors.category19().by(function(d){return d.group});
```

Comment: Update for people finding this: Protovis is no longer under development, they replaced it with d3.js: http://d3js.org/