# JavaScript network visualization?

Tags: javascript, html, visualization

I'm looking for a library to visualize a network.

I just need to add some nodes(node has text on them), add edges between them, (edges are directed and have text on them).I don't want to set the position of anything by hand.

I'd like API simple as:

```
var node1 = X.addNode(1, "Hello"),
    node2 = X.addNode(2, "World");
X.addEdge(node1, node2, "helloworld");
```

I've searched for hours, looked after arborjs, sigma.js, d3.js, JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit, none of them satisfied me.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886705/javascript-network-visualization and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749706/network-diagram-using-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS).
Amazon Visualization [sample](http://www.yasiv.com/amazon#/Search?q=graph%20drawing&category=Books&lang=US) by VivaGraphJS.

Layout configuration [sample](http://www.yasiv.com/graphs#Bai/bfwa398), uses WebGL as a renderer.

Answer (score 3):

We produce [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html), but note this is a commercial library, not open source. I'm not sure exactly why the open source libraries you listed failed, but certainly forming the graph, setting the geometry and labels are all fairly trivial function calls.

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem with sigma.js? The library's website has a very simple example to draw the nodes and edges:

```
var sigRoot = document.getElementById('sig');
var sigInst = sigma.init(sigRoot);
sigInst.addNode('hello',{
label: 'Hello',
color: '#ff0000'
}).addNode('world',{
label: 'World !',
color: '#00ff00'
}).addEdge('hello_world','hello','world').draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this page of sigma.js
http://sigmajs.org/examples/a_plugin_example.html
and you will see how they do a random or a circular layout.

Answer (score 2):

I found this javascript library to be helpful. Check out the network examples page:

[visjs](http://visjs.org/network_examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try out [cne-tnetwork](https://github.com/telefonicaid/cne-tnetwork). It is javascript visualization library to create and draw network graphs. It is SVG-based and HTML 5 compatible. It is publicly available on github, licensed under the GNU Afferro license. You can find how to use it in the [readme](https://github.com/telefonicaid/cne-tnetwork/blob/master/README.md) of the library. It has a mode to drag the nodes. The links between nodes can be unidirectional, bidirectional or even "buses" that connect several elements. With CSS you can customize all your styles (nodes, links, arrows, buses...).